# Interface doesn't support scan

Tags: debian, wifi

i'm using debian and after a reboot wifi is not working.

```
uname -a
    Linux debian-v**** 5.10.0-0.bps.7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.40-1-bpo10+1 (2021-06-04)x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When i'm trying to perform a scan i have the following output

```
sudo iwlist wlp59s0 scan 
    wlp59s0 Interface doesn't support scanning: Network is down
```

And iwconfig has the  following output

```
sudo iwconfig
    

lo    no wireless extensions.
    
wlp59s0    IEEE 802.11 ESSID:off/any Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Powersoff
    
    Retry short Limit:7 RTS thr:off
    
    Fragnent thr:off
    
    Encryption key:off
    
    Power Management:on
    
    decker no wireless extensions.
    
    br-378afab39a77 no wireless extensions.
    
    th4050480 no wireless extensions.
    
    eth096c453 no wireless extensions.
    
    weth362b042 no wireless extensions
```

.
And i have nothing in demsg

```
sudo dmesg | grep wifi

intuifi-cc-a0-59.ucode

***@debian-***

4.958688] inlifi 0000:3b:00.0: enabling device (0000 0002)

4.970953] intiri 0000:3b:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intuifi-cc-a0-59.

4.970960] ilifi 0000:3b:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver

4.970963] istifi 0000:3b:00.0: TLV FR FSEQ VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22

4.971159] istifi 0000:3b:00.0: Loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode op node int 5.1532083 ilifi 0000:3b:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340

5.346213) istifi 0000:3b:00.0: base H address: 5c:80:b6:73:20:00

5.364087] ilifi 0000:3b:00.0 wlp59s0: renamed from wlan0

499.501561) (NULL device ): firmware: direct-loading firmware intsifi-cc-a0-59.ucode
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using nmcli.
To list available wifi access points (aka routers ) in the range:

```
nmcli dev wifi
```

To connect to a network for the first time, follow the example in the man nmcli:

```
nmcli dev wifi con "Cafe Hotspot 1" password caffeine name "My cafe"
```

To check if you are connected, use `nmcli device status` or `nmcli dev list` (14.04) , or `nmcli dev show` for 15.04

If you already have a connection established, nmcli con list for 14.04 or nmcli con show for 15.04.

If you want to connect to one of those connections listed by `nmcli con lsit`, do `nmcli con up id "My Network Name"`

Comment: Nmcli was not available after the reboot...

Answer (score 0):

Here I will describe the way to quickly fix this issue.

Validated on "Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)" with Raspberry Pi5.

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

dmesg | grep brcmfmac
[    5.126350] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x15264345
[    5.134616] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    5.134895] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,5-model-b.bin failed with error -2
[    5.134948] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    5.135002] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin failed with error -2
[    6.144231] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

1. Cloning Wi-Fi firmware repository

   ```
   git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/RPi-Distro/firmware-nonfree.git
   ```
2. The wifi mode for raspberry pi 5 is brcmfmc43455, you only need to copy the files for brcmfmc43455.

   ```
   cp firmware-nonfree/debian/config/brcm80211/cypress/cyfmac43455-sdio-standard.bin /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin
   cp firmware-nonfree/debian/config/brcm80211/cypress/cyfmac43455-sdio.clm_blob /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.clm_blob
   cp firmware-nonfree/debian/config/brcm80211/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt /lib/firmware/brcm/
   ```
3. Create symlinks for the firmware files, make sure you have following symlinks.

   ```
   ln -s /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,5-model-b.bin /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin
   ln -s /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,5-model-b.clm_blob /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,5-model-b.bin
   ln -s /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,5-model-b.txt
   ```
4. Reboot your system

   ```
   reboot
   ```
5. Now, you can validate the wlan0 back to work.

   ```
   rfkill
       ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
        0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
        1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
   ```

   ```
   iwlist wlan0 scan
   ```